# Searching Erdős paper on the lower bound of the Ramsey number

Tags: research

In the [wikipedia article on the probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) mentions in the paragraph "First Example" a proof attributed to Erdős. It is attributed to him in a 1947 paper. There is no 1947 paper in the references, neither is it mentioned in the talk.

Where can I find this paper (title? download link?)

[Related Question that doesn't mention the paper either.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928518/algebra-in-erd%C5%91ss-proof-of-lower-bound-for-ramsey-number)

He wrote a [lot of papers](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/Erdos.html) in 1947, and I can't find a matching one by title alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in *Some Remarks on the Theory of Graphs*, available [here](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1947-09.pdf) (bad scan) or [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-53/issue-4/Some-remarks-on-the-theory-of-graphs/bams/1183510596.full) if you have access.  Theorem I contains the result that $f(k, k) > 2^{k/2}$, which is what the example in the wiki article is about.  I think the proof in the paper is the one in the footnote (a) of the wiki article.

Comment: there is no paywall before your second link :)

Comment: good to hear! $\phantom{Erdos}$

Comment: Am I blind or does the proof in the paper use the counting argument, and not a probability argument?

Comment: like I said in the answer, the proof in the paper is the non-probabilistic one in footnote (a) of the wiki article directly beneath the "First example" section